# Xcode center image while keeping square

Tags: swift, xcode

Swift/xcode newbie here, be gentle.

I'm trying to set an image to be squared (around 160x160px) in the center of the screen on iphones and ipads.

Is there a way to set the coordinates per device. or any method around this?

constraints just scretch the image out.

Comment: "constraints just scretch the image out" Not if you use _centering_ constraints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty new to Xcode, but I've recently learned about auto layout / constraints.

Select your image view and apply width and height constraints via the pin dialogue box (screenshot below), then open your alignment constraints and select center horizontally and center vertically. Then just apply your constraints and voila!

Like I said I'm still learning so if this is wrong, anybody please feel free to jump in.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yep, that was it, didn't see the alignment constraints

Answer (score 2):

Or you can also use **Aspect Ratio** constraint if you need a larger or smaller image and making sure the image is always square, with **Horizontally in Container** and **Vertically in Container** Constraint set.